# S = {3, 5, 7 , 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21} find number of subsets with 5 element

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So the question asks 
How many subsets A of S contain 5 elements, with the smallest element less or equal to 12.

What I did was at least one element has to be chosen from {3, 5, 7 ,9 ,11}
and other 4 slots can be filled by other 9 elements. In binomial expression, I did

> A = 5C1 * 9C4 =  630

I thought the number was too big, so I compared with finding all Subset A containing 5 element which is

> A = 10C5 = 252

which concludes that there is something wrong in my logic. Can anyone guide me to right direction?

Comment: I guess I could approad this problem by subtracting one case which does not have the smallest element greater than 12 which is only once case {13,15,17,19,21} from the 10C5 = 252. The final answer being 251?

Comment: That's correct. There is only one five element subset with all elements greater than $12$, so you just have to subtract that one, giving $251$.

Comment: So only 1 subset has them all greater than 12, so the answer must be ${10\choose 5}-1$.

Comment: @fleablood could you look at the question --> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657257/using-combinatoric-as-getting-number-of-subsets-in-a-specified-format/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are double (or more) counting the subsets that have more than one element less than $12$.  The subset $\{3,5,17,19,21\}$ is counted twice, once with $3$ being the first slot and once with $5$ being the first slot.  Those with more elements less than $12$ are counted more.

Comment: Okay! thanks! I will approach it differently