# Using combinatoric as getting number of subsets in a specified format

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$$A = { 1, a, 2, b, 3, c }$$

How many subsets involving $4$ elements of the set A does contain ($1$ **or** $2$) but not $a$?

My way to go is, to begin with, the withdrawal of $a$, then finding the number of the subsets involving 4 elements and `not` containing $1$ **and** $2$ since subtracting it from the former case yields what I wish to get.

$$C{5 \choose 4} -C{3 \choose 4} $$

What I wonder is the result of $C{3 \choose 4}$ while [the result on the link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3c4) gives $0$. How? I don't know another way around to solve the problem.

By the way, the answer is $5$.

Comment: maybe you meant 4 choose 3? you can't choose 4 out of 3 elements

Comment: @BinyaminR yes, I know I **may not** but if the set $A$ contains one more element or more like 7 or more, I'd say $C{6 \choose 4}$ - $C{4 \choose 4}$ for 7 elements for the problem, for example. Wouldn't I?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but the number of subsets not containing 1 and 2, is 4 choose 4 =  1 , not 3 choose 3

Comment: @BinyaminR yes but because we're looking for among subsets only containing 4 elements. Subsets not containing 1 and 2 and 'a' in my question's latter case.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of subsets of size 4 of $\{ 1, a, 2, b, 3, c \}$ that **do not** include 1, a and 2, is indeed equal to the amount of subsets of size 4 of $\{ b, 3, c \}$. I think that you can state without further derivation that this equals 0, since you cannot pick 4 elements from a set of 3 elements.

Hence, you indeed obtain that there are ${ 5 \choose 4 } - 0 = 5$ ways to pick 4 elements from the set $\{ 1, a, 2, b, 3, c \}$ that do contain 1 or 2 but not a.